# Categorising eating habits in a single word or short term

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Is there a word or term to describe preferred eating habits (other than "eating habits")? That is to say, a catch-all category to describe the states of being a carnivore, vegan, pescitarian, fruititarian, or vegetarian etc.

The usage is primarily in a programming context, where a food type can be any of the above. However, I'm also interested just to know if such a work exists?

Comment: Why does a good question promptly earn down votes and close votes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd sugget [diet](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/diet?s=t) or diet preference/diet of preference/dietry preferences

> 4. the foods eaten, as by a particular person or group: The native diet consists of fish and fruit.